# Add class to table rows that contain Dog 1 and rows in between

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is automatically generated so I cannot add classes/id's etc by adding HTML so I am trying to do this using js. I truncated the content, but basically I want to add class "dog1" to the rows that pertain to Dog 1 and class "dog2" to the rows that pertain to Dog 2.

```html
<table>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Name</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Age</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Weight</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Date of last appointment</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Number</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Acceptance</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Allergies</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Details</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Name</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Name</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Age</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Weight</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Date of last appointment</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Number</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Acceptance</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Allergies</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

So I tried using:

```
$('span:contains("Dog 1").closest('tr').addClass('dog1');
```

But the problem is there are some rows that do not contain "Dog 1", (ex: Acceptance, Date of last appointment)

Any suggestions on how to grab those ones too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find all the tr in the table that contains a span with Dog 1.
2. For each row, if it contains Dog 1, Dog 2, Dog 3: set the class attribute to "dog1", "dog2", "dog3", ...

```js
let dogCounter = 1;
let classAttribute = '';
const $trs = $('span:contains("Dog 1")').first().closest('table').find('tr');

$trs.each((i, tr) => {
  const selector = 'span:contains("Dog '+dogCounter+'")';
  if ($(tr).find(selector).length) {
   classAttribute = 'dog'+dogCounter;
    dogCounter++;
  }
  $(tr).addClass(classAttribute);
})
```

```css
.dog1 {
  color: red;
}
.dog2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Name</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Age</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Weight</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Date of last appointment</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Number</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Acceptance</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 1 Allergies</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Details</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Name</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Name</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Age</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Weight</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Date of last appointment</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Number</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Acceptance</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Dog 2 Allergies</span></td></tr>
</table>
```